# Using Try/Catch to test four File.Move tasks to see if file exists

Tags: c#, ssis

I should start by saying I'm new to C#. I have four lines of code in a script that each rename a file in a specific directory. In order for my program to successfully run, it needs these four files and the files need to be named a specific name. These lines of code are processed individually, so the first line can rename the file if it's found, but the second line could error out if the file is not found. Another scenario could be that the first line of code errors out if the specific file it's looking for is not found and the rest of the lines of code will fail to process because of the script halts. I added these lines of script to a single try and will attempt to catch each exception individually, but since the code doesn't get past the first line of code that produces an error this approach doesn't appear to work.

If one file is missing, I want to store the name of the missing file (or a specific message) in a variable. if multiple files are missing, I want to store multiple messages in the variable to be sent via an SSIS package.

```
File.Move(fileDirectory_Dest + "EOYReportPRF.xls", fileDirectory_Dest + "EOY_PRF.xls");
File.Move(fileDirectory_Dest + "PayrollEOY.xls", fileDirectory_Dest + "EOY_SU.xls");
File.Move(fileDirectory_Dest + "PRFFundingStatement.xls", fileDirectory_Dest + "FS_PRF.xls");
File.Move(fileDirectory_Dest + "SUFundingStatement.xls", fileDirectory_Dest + "FS_SU.xls");
```

I want to cycle through all four lines of code and store the error text in a variable named User::MessageText in my SSIS package. I then will use this variable to send an email to a user, but I can take care of that part.

UPDATE:
Adding the whole snippet of code to help understand the current situation.

```
try
            {
                foreach (FileInfo fi in dirInfo_Source.EnumerateFiles())
                {

                    string newFileName = Regex.Replace(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name), "[0-9]|[.,/ -]", "").TrimEnd()+ fi.Extension;
                    fi.MoveTo(fileDirectory_Dest + newFileName);
                    //i++;.Replace(" ", "_") + i 

                }
                ///Rename Files
                File.Move(fileDirectory_Dest + "EOYReportPalladia.xls", fileDirectory_Dest + "EOY_Palladia.xls");
                File.Move(fileDirectory_Dest + "PayrollEOY.xls", fileDirectory_Dest + "EOY_SUS.xls");
                File.Move(fileDirectory_Dest + "PRFFundingStatement.xls", fileDirectory_Dest + "FS_Palladia.xls");
                File.Move(fileDirectory_Dest + "SUSFundingStatement.xls", fileDirectory_Dest + "FS_SUS.xls");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(fileDirectory_Dest);
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: Never use exceptions to drive your logic. By the way why don't you use File.Exists?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I edited my request to indicate that I'm new. I would still need to test to see if files are missing, but don't really know the best, most efficient way to get to my goal. If I was to use File.Exists, and the file doesn't exist, wouldnt that be an exception also?

Comment: @Steve File access requires exception handling anyway - maybe destination is unwritable? In the case of IO it’s often an “exception” to the rule.

Comment: @user2864740 So an exception to an exception...

Comment: How about using a loop to move the files, storing all exception messages/ details to report? Make sure to separate recoverable and non-recoverable cases. The file names might be the sequence being looped, eg.

Comment: @user2864740 I added the snippet of code that includes the try/catch. Are you saying that I should dynamically rename the files as they are enumerated? I could add multiple exceptions that add a string to the variable i mentioned, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using exceptions when you can use a less expensive way to check. Of course, when dealing with files you could always encounter 'exceptional' situations and this is the right job for exception handling

You could check the existance of the files before running the File.Move block of code with

```
try
{
    string fileDirectory_Dest = @"E:\temp\";
    List<string> files = new List<string>
    {
        fileDirectory_Dest + "EOYReportPRF.xls",
        fileDirectory_Dest + "PayrollEOY.xls",
        fileDirectory_Dest + "PRFFundingStatement.xls",
        fileDirectory_Dest + "SUFundingStatement.xls"
    };
    var errors = files.Where(x => !File.Exists(x)).Select(x => x);
    if(errors.Any())
        Console.WriteLine("Files missing\r\n" + string.Join(Environment.NewLine, errors));
}
catch
{
    Logger.Error("Error processing files");
    throw; 
}
```

Comment: I'm going to try to apply this to the code and see where it takes me, thanks!

Comment: Steve, It looks like I should be able to apply this inthe loop that moves and standardizes the file names. Is this more efficient? As the loop locates the file and attempts to move it, couldn;t I test that there is a match or not and store that in the log? I updated my original post with the snippet of code that performs the task.

Comment: Well, the idea is to check if a File.Exists or not before trying to do anything with it. So I suppose that you could add the logic to your loop. Checking if a file exists is a lot more efficient than recurring to an exception. You can notice the difference even with a single file

Comment: the Logger.Error() line is stating that Logger doesn't exist in current conext. Is this a built in feature?

Comment: No, this was just an example. In an exception handler or you have a way to deal with the exception or you do nothing. Usually I log the situation using a Log library like NLog or Log4Net and then I let the exception going up the stack chain until I can treat it in some way. You can replace that line with your own logging library or remove the whole try/catch

Comment: Thanks, Steve. I'm learning a lot from posting on the forums and I appreciate your patience.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution to be the best for me. Easy to understand and error handling can easily be changed. You can handle the error messages individually

```
using System.IO;
using System;

...

try
{
    File.Move(fileDirectory_Dest + "EOYReportPRF.xls", fileDirectory_Dest + "EOY_PRF.xls");
    File.Move(fileDirectory_Dest + "PayrollEOY.xls", fileDirectory_Dest + "EOY_SU.xls");
    File.Move(fileDirectory_Dest + "PRFFundingStatement.xls", fileDirectory_Dest + "FS_PRF.xls");
    File.Move(fileDirectory_Dest + "SUFundingStatement.xls", fileDirectory_Dest + "FS_SU.xls");
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
{
    // UnauthorizedAccessException code here 
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e)
{
    // DirectoryNotFoundException code here 
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
catch
{
    // ... other Errors
    Console.WriteLine("Other Errors");
}
```